# Having problems in swift 3 when using Struct and functions

Tags: ios, swift, function, class, struct

I trying to make a cash register calculator app that helps me count money from the register faster. for example: instead of adding up all the $20dollar notes, I can just enter how many singles of $20 I have and the app can calculate the total. This is my code, I used a Struct and a function but I had errors running the code. Thanks

```
struct Money {
    oneCent: Double
    fiveCent: Double
    tenCent: Double
    quater: Double
    fiftyCent: Double
    rollCent: Double
    rollFive: Double
    rollTen: Double
    rollQuater: Double
    dollarCoin: Double
    dollar: Double
    fiveDollar: Double
    tenDollar : Double
    twentyDollar: Double
    fiftyDollar: Double
    hundredDollar: Double
    oneCent: Double
}

func moneyCalcualate (value at : Money, copies: Double){

    var total : Double = 0.00
    for i in at{
        switch i {
           case oneCent : total = 0.01 * copies
           case fiveCent : total = 0.05 * copies
            case tenCent : total = 0.10 * copies
            case  quater : total = 0.25 * copies
            case  fiftyCent : total = 0.50 * copies
            case  rollCent: total = 0.01 * copies
            case  rollFive: total = 0.01 * copies
            case  rollTen : total = 0.01 * copies
            case  rollQuater : total = 10.00 * copies
            case  dollarCoin : total = 1.00 * copies
            case  dollar : total = 1.00 * copies
            case  fiveDollar : total = 5.00 * copies
            case  tenDollar : total = 10.00 * copies
            case twentyDollar : total = 20.00 * copies
            case fiftyDollar : total = 50.00 * copies
            case hundredDollar : total = 100.00 * copies

        }
    }
    return total
}


moneyCalcualate(value: quater, copies: 2.0)
```

Comment: This code does not even compile; there are quite a few errors here. Tell us which error, specifically, that you need help with, and if applicable, what you tried already.

Comment: How can you start a for loop from this 'value at : Money' variable in moneyCalcualate function?

Comment: You need to define your properties using let or var

Comment: `let oneCent: Double
   let   fiveCent: Double
    let  tenCent: Double
   let   quater: Double
  let    fiftyCent: Double
    let  rollCent: Double
    let  rollFive: Double
   let   rollTen: Double
  let    rollQuater: Double
  let    dollarCoin: Double
   let   dollar: Double
   let   fiveDollar: Double
   let   tenDollar : Double
    let  twentyDollar: Double
   let   fiftyDollar: Double
   let   hundredDollar: Double`

Comment: Also you have oneCent twice in your code (redeclaration)

Comment: *quater* is a term related to chemistry. The coin is a *quarter*

Comment: Thanks guys. I have now declared my variables and deleted repeated code. this is my error                                                                                                     error: protocolsInSwift.playground:26:14: error: type 'Money' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'
    for i in at{
             ^

error: protocolsInSwift.playground:47:12: error: unexpected non-void return value in void function
    return total

Comment: There is a general misunderstanding: `Money` is **one** object which contains all notes and coins. It is not a collection type (first error). And If you want to return something you have to declare a return type (second error). And please edit the question to fix the compile issues.

Comment: @vadian what do u mean by declare a collection type?

Comment: `for i in at` requires a collection type, an array containing multiple items. It's not clear what you are going to accomplish.

Comment: I think he's trying to loop over all of `Money`'s properties?  Not sure why though, since going through each one individually would be less complicated than the switch inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical case for an `enum`. Declare all your money types as cases and assign raw values to each. Then you can create a function which will return the total for a given number of copies for current type.

Here's an example:

```
enum Money: Double {
    case oneCent = 0.01
    case fiveCent = 0.05
    case tenCent = 0.1
    case quarter = 0.25

    func total(numberOfCopies: Int) -> Double {
        return self.rawValue * Double(numberOfCopies)
    }
}
```

You call it like this:

```
let moneyInFiveCents = Money.fiveCent
let fiveCents = moneyInFiveCents.total(numberOfCopies: 5)
print(fiveCents)
// prints 0.25

let moneyInQuarters = Money.quarter
let quarters = moneyInQuarters.total(numberOfCopies: 5)
print(quarters)
// prints 1.25

print(fiveCents + quarters)
// prints 1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way..

```
enum Money {
case oneCent
case fiveCent
case tenCent
case quater
case fiftyCent
case rollCent
case rollFive
case rollTen
case rollQuater
case dollarCoin
case dollar
case fiveDollar
case tenDollar 
case twentyDollar
case fiftyDollar
case hundredDollar



static let all : [Money] = [.oneCent , .fiveCent , .tenCent , .quater, .fiftyCent, .rollCent, .rollFive, .rollTen, .rollQuater, .dollarCoin, .dollar, .fiveDollar, .tenDollar, .twentyDollar, .fiftyDollar, .hundredDollar]
}

func moneyCalcualate (value at : Money, copies: Double) -> Double{


var total : Double = 0.00


switch at {
case .oneCent : total = 0.01 * copies
case .fiveCent : total = 0.05 * copies
case .tenCent : total = 0.10 * copies
case .quater : total = 0.25 * copies
case  .fiftyCent : total = 0.50 * copies
case  .rollCent: total = 0.01 * copies
case  .rollFive: total = 0.01 * copies
case  .rollTen : total = 0.01 * copies
case  .rollQuater : total = 10.00 * copies
case  .dollarCoin : total = 1.00 * copies
case .dollar : total = 1.00 * copies
case  .fiveDollar : total = 5.00 * copies
case  .tenDollar : total = 10.00 * copies
case .twentyDollar : total = 20.00 * copies
case .fiftyDollar : total = 50.00 * copies
case .hundredDollar : total = 100.00 * copies

}

return total
}


moneyCalcualate(value: .quater, copies: 2.0)
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks Agent smith. What is the purpose of the static let? This is my first time of seeying it. Does it turn all the values in our money enum into am array?

Comment: I'm making an array of all values of enum so that we can iterate through them. @Perewillz